# Iterate over a dict or list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, loops

Just wrote some nasty code that iterates over a `dict` or a `list` in Python. I have a feeling this was not the best way to go about it.

The problem is that in order to iterate over a dict, this is the convention:

```
for key in dict_object:
    dict_object[key] = 1
```

But modifying the object properties by key does not work if the same thing is done on a list:

```
# Throws an error because the value of key is the property value, not 
#     the list index:

for key in list_object:
    list_object[key] = 1
```

The way I solved this problem was to write this nasty code:

```
if isinstance(obj, dict):
    for key in obj:
        do_loop_contents(obj, key)
elif isinstance(obj, list):
    for i in xrange(0, len(obj)):
        do_loop_contents(obj, i)

def do_loop_contents(obj, key):
    obj[key] = 1
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've never needed to do this, ever.  But if I did, I'd probably do something like this:

```
seq_iter = x if isinstance(x, dict) else xrange(len(x))
```

For example, in function form:

```
>>> def seq_iter(obj):
...     return obj if isinstance(obj, dict) else xrange(len(obj))
... 
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> for i in seq_iter(x):
...     x[i] = 99
... 
>>> x
[99, 99, 99]
>>> 
>>> x = {1: 2, 2:3, 3:4}
>>> for i in seq_iter(x):
...     x[i] = 99
... 
>>> x
{1: 99, 2: 99, 3: 99}
```

Comment: Just spotted you have an answer very similar to mine. The only difference is you are using `xrange()` (which is okay), but the result is the same or very similar. +1

Comment: Shouldn't the line be `return obj if isinstance(obj, dict) else xrange(len(obj))`?

Comment: @tobias_k: good catch!  Python's scoping meets in-line edit. :^)

Answer (score 6):

This is the correct way, but if for some reason you need to treat these two objects the same way, you can create an iterable that will return indexes / keys no matter what:

```
def common_iterable(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return obj
    else:
        return (index for index, value in enumerate(obj))
```

Which will behave in the way you wanted:

```
>>> d = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> for index in common_iterable(d):
    d[index] = 0

>>> d
{'a': 0, 'b': 0}
>>> for index in common_iterable(l):
    l[index] = 0

>>> l
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Or probably more efficiently, using a generator:

```
def common_iterable(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key in obj:
            yield key
    else:
        for index, value in enumerate(obj):
            yield index
```

Comment: This isn't actually an `iterator`, it just transforms a `list` or `dict` in to an iterable of a consistent format.  You could define an iterator factory that does this with the iterator protocol using `next` and `__iter__` though.

Comment: @sr2222: Okay, it is iterable. I could also make it a generator to probably boost performance a little.

Comment: Your second version of `common_iterable` is unnecessary. `(index for index, value in enumerate(obj))` from the first version is already a generator and `for key in obj: yield key` just adds overhead to what was perfectly fine in the first version of `common_iterable`

Answer (score 5):

To be pythonic and ducktype-y, and also to follow "ask for forgiveness not permission", you could do something like:

```
try:
    iterator = obj.iteritems()
except AttributeError:
    iterator = enumerate(obj)
for reference, value in iterator:
    do_loop_contents(obj, reference)
```

Though if all you need is the key/index:

```
try:
    references = obj.keys()
except AttributeError:
    references = range(len(obj))
for reference in references:
    do_loop_contents(obj, reference)
```

Or as a function:

```
def reference_and_value_iterator(iterable):
    try:
        return iterable.iteritems()
    except AttributeError:
        return enumerate(iterable)

for reference, value in reference_and_value_iterator(obj):
    do_loop_contents(obj, reference)
```

Or for just the references:

```
def references(iterable):
    try:
        return iterable.keys()
    except AttributeError:
        return range(len(iterable))

for reference in references(obj):
    do_loop_contents(obj, reference)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test_list = [2, 3, 4]
for i, entry in enumerate(test_list):
    test_list[i] = entry * 2
print(test_list)  # Gives: [4, 6, 8]
```

But you probably want a list comprehension:

```
test_list = [2, 3, 4]
test_list = [entry * 2 for entry in test_list]
print(test_list)  # Gives: [4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want to have a different code depending on if the object you are trying to change is a dict or a list.

```
if type(object)==type([]):
    for key in range(len(object)):
        object[key]=1
elif type(object)==type({}): #use 'else' if you know that object will be a dict if not a list
    for key in object:
        object[key]=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this post while searching for a better one, here's how I did it.

```
for row in [dict_or_list] if not type(dict_or_list) is list else dict_or_list:
    for i,v in row.items():
        print(i,v)
```